# Constructing Coupled Inductors with Particular Coupling Coefficient

Tags: rf, transformer, inductor, mutual-inductance

I'm curious about the design of RF transformers with purposely designed non-unity coupling coefficient. I can see how this would be done in an IC, but how feasible is it at the discrete component level?

For example, if I made two air core inductors and placed them axially aligned in close proximity, what kind of ranges of coupling coefficient could I hope to achieve? And importantly, how accurate could I get that coupling coefficient to be?

If I wanted to get high, but precise, coupling coefficient, could I use a toroidal transformer? I'm thinking not, since having tight control over the coupling would be fairly difficult.

What piqued my interest on this topic was reading about T-coil peaking, which requires very particular coupled inductors.

Thanks.

Comment: If you can tolerate the math, [here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://itnan.ru/post.php?c%3D2%26p%3D294879) is something.

Comment: In looking at [this article](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/analog/article/21807815/whats-all-this-tcoil-stuff-anyhow) it appears that the tweaking the capacitor is more the problem. Interesting topic. And I'm +1 your question because of that.

Comment: Math is always appreciated, thanks for the link.

Comment: @jonk That article got me interested as well. Unfortunately I've only been able to find theory, but not much mention on how those guys at Tektronix actually implemented their magical T-coils...

Comment: The 1st Japanese transistor radios mastered this in miniature tuning ferrite screws in the centre of two vertical coils in a shielded ferrite shell for the twin peaks with higher Q wider bandwidth filters for AM and IF with low passband ripple.

Comment: @Tony Stewart EE75 Wouldn't using a ferrite tuning screw affect the self inductances as well as the mutual inductance? So one could not be tuned without the other. Unless they planned for that somehow.

Comment: It was designed with a fixed coupling ferrite lead screw to vary the inductance ratio of primary and secondary by geometry to have the required mutual to mean inductance ratio. (Lm/Sqrt(Lp*Ls) https://antiqueradiosandparts.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=66_388&page=2

Comment: Seems like an XY case. Mutually-coupled resonators are often required to transfer power efficiently *over a very narrow frequency range*. Resonator coils are mutually-coupled by physical separation. The amount of mutual coupling is constrained by resonator Q (quality factor) for maximum power transfer. Resonating capacitors are needed to tune-out all the crazy reactances to deliver real power efficiently. I think this is the case that @TonyStewartEE75 outlines. OP seems to want something more general.

Comment: Weakly coupled coaxial coils must never exceed the diameter and step-up step-down coaxial coils both co- resonant with high Q will benefit from the higher impedance mutual coupling for impedance matching towards MPT . Then centric Ferrite  coaxial rod  flat or round can improve axial coupling greatly over low impedance air coils with the largest coil diameter or double D overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I'm curious about the design of RF transformers with purposely
> designed non-unity coupling coefficient.*

If you are looking for some degree of precision in the value of k then use near-unity coupling transformers and use an external shielded inductor to create the uncoupled inductance you require.

> *For example, if I made two air core inductors and placed them axially
> aligned in close proximity, what kind of ranges of coupling
> coefficient could I hope to achieve? And importantly, how accurate
> could I get that coupling coefficient to be?*

From zero to probably around 0.5 coupling coefficient. The trouble is that without an extensive analysis of the fields using a finite element tool, you wouldn't really know if your coupling is within +/- 50% of your target AND, other things in the vicinity could easily influence that coupling.

> *If I wanted to get high, but precise, coupling coefficient, could I
> use a toroidal transformer? I'm thinking not, since having tight
> control over the coupling would be fairly difficult.*

Use a toroid and an external shielded inductor to create the leakage inductance.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, if I made two air core inductors and placed them axially aligned in close proximity, what kind of ranges of coupling coefficient could I hope to achieve? And importantly, how accurate could I get that coupling coefficient to be?

Way back in my early engineering days, we needed to implement a 50 MHz and a 500 MHz bandpass filter, with very good Q and deep stopbands. The solution was a piece of cross-linked polystyrene rod about 10 mm diameter, threaded coarse M10 for the 500 MHz filter, and somewhat finer for the 50 MHz filter. This was then wound with a few discrete coils of wire. The thread defined the turns spacing of each coil, and the spacing between coils very accurately.

These coils only produced very low coupling, but I suppose the same technique with overlapping turns could approach a coupling of unity, if the inter-coil capacitance could be tolerated.